# Building 3rd party content filtering plugins for Exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We want to build a 3rd party plug-in to assess inbound and outbound messages according to certain criteria. Then we want to either change the message metadata or forward it, if it meets a particular criteria. It cannot be done with regexes or keywords. It is really a custom set of actions.

I found several leads, but it is not clear whether it can be achieved. Here are the leads:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#GetMessages - Outlook API is being deprecated but it seems that Graph API is taking over the functionality.
- Exchange Web Services (EWS): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-access-email-as-a-delegate-by-using-ews-in-exchange - but it's unclear whether our service can access user's messages with administrative privileges.
- Exchange Online Protection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/office-365-security/exchange-online-protection-overview?view=o365-worldwide - but is there a plug-in architecture?
- Built-in content filtering: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/antispam-and-antimalware/antispam-protection/content-filtering?view=exchserver-2019 - again, is there a way to embed a plug-in?
- Finally, **transport agents**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/transport-agents/transport-agents?view=exchserver-2019 - that seems to be just the ticket, but I wonder if there's a catch?

Dear Exchange gurus, what the advantages and the disadvantages of every approach?

Comment: Is it for Exchange Online or Exchange OnPrem, if its OnPrem then use Transport Agents if its Exchange Online then Transport Agent won't work there isn't anything in the Online Pipeline that is extensible you can control routing with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/use-connectors-to-configure-mail-flow/set-up-connectors-to-route-mail and then process with your own infrastructure.

Comment: Thank you, @GlenScales. We want to build a plug-in with as wide scope as possible, but if we had to choose, that would be OnPrem. The redirection is an interesting workaround, but sounds more of a hack. What can be extended in Exchange Online though?

Comment: It not really a hack, AFAIK this is they way most third parties implement this type of solution in Office365 example https://cdn.exclaimer.com/Docs/ConnectorsAU1.pdf as you can't run code in the Transport pipeline in the cloud and doing it at the individual mailbox level with EWS or the Graph has only limited functionality.